# Get subscriber count with YouTube Data API v3 on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, api, youtube

how can I get subscriber count with YouTube Data API v3 on Android studio?
I can play video but, can't get subscriber count, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscriber count is a property of [Channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) class.

Here's a working example that allows you to search for a channel, and returns the subscriber count of all returned results.

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTubeRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

class Main {

    public static final String API_KEY = "YOUR KEY HERE";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(
                new NetHttpTransport(),
                new JacksonFactory(),
                new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                }
        })
        .setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample")
        .setYouTubeRequestInitializer(new YouTubeRequestInitializer(API_KEY))
        .build();


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Search for channel:");
        String queryTerm = input.nextLine();

        YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("snippet");
        search.setQ(queryTerm);
        search.setType("channel");

        SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
        List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
        if (searchResultList != null) {
            for (SearchResult searchResult : searchResultList) {
                String channelId = searchResult.getSnippet().getChannelId();

                YouTube.Channels.List channels = youtube.channels().list("snippet, statistics");
                channels.setId(channelId);

                ChannelListResponse channelResponse = channels.execute();

                for (Channel c : channelResponse.getItems()) {
                    System.out.println("Name: " + c.getSnippet().getTitle());
                    System.out.println("Subs: " + c.getStatistics().getSubscriberCount());
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

With the input: H3 Podcast, you get the results:

```
Name: H3 Podcast
Subs: 511821

Name: h3h3Productions
Subs: 4241196

Name: The H3 Podcast
Subs: 2

Name: Baited!
Subs: 236641

Name: Ethan and Hila
Subs: 1633842
```

I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it, but it works.

Comment: I saw channel statistics.but, how can I use that? I'm new with API's.

Answer (score 0):

try this youtube api

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=CHANNEL_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Hope this is Helpful;